# How to make a collision event for a person jumping

Tags: javascript

How would one make a collision and gravity event for a character to jump and colliding with a enemy?

Say i want my character to jump 20px and then come back down but if there is no ground under then they continue to fall.

Here is my coding, The div with the id person can move left right and up with the arrow keys but i need to make it so when he jumps he will come back down but if he collides with another div he is too stop, but if he doesn't he is to continue falling.   Also if there is any chance you can help me make it so I can push the jump button and a move button so he does both at the same time would be helpful

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(){move()});


function move(){
var spot = document.getElementById('person').offsetTop;
var lr = document.getElementById('person').offsetLeft;
var y = spot + 5;
var z = spot - 5;
var w = lr + 5;
var v = lr - 5;

var map = []; // Or you could call it "key"
onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e){
    e = e || event; // to deal with IE
    map[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';
    /*insert conditional here*/
if(map[38]){
  document.getElementById('person').style.top = z + "px";
 }else if(map[37]){
  document.getElementById('person').style.left = v + "px";
 }else if(map[39]){
  document.getElementById('person').style.left = w + "px";
 }
}
}
```

```html
<div id="person" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;top:490px; position: absolute ; background-color:#00F"></div>
<div id="ground" style="width:auto; position:relative; top:500px; height: 5px; background-color:#000"></div>
<div id="wall" style="width: 30px; height:30px; top:470px; left:100px; position:relative; background-color:#000"></div>
```

Comment: try [Phaser](http://phaser.io)

Answer (score 1):

A quick bit of game theory here. You should read up on articles or tutorials on how this is best achieved for your desired effects.

Your ground and character are both game objects, possibly both with a width, height, x and y co-ordinariate.

You will need to apply a value of gravity on your character on every update if the player is not colliding with an object on the y-axis (below it) that will move the character down.

```
.(x,y)----------
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|              |
----------------
```

`Where player.x and y is the top left of it's box`

You can calculate this collision by using `player.y-player.length` (to get you to the bottom of the player) `>=` is greater than or equals `ground.y` the upper location of the ground. In this case don't apply gravity.

For the bow and arrow you would do the same only checking the left, right, bottom and top don't collide with another object.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to evaluate a physics library, such as Matter.js or PhysicsJS. You can also look at other evaluations at https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Physics-libraries